# why can't I access ApplicationContext from ApplicationContextAware implemented bean

Tags: spring, springjunit4classrunner

I have a Spring JUnit tester class `MySimpleTester`:

@

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/spring/mySimpleConfig.xml"})
public class MySimpleTester {

@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myAdapter = (MyAdapter) applicationContext.getBean("myAdapter");
    }

@test 
public void testGetSimpleList() {
        List<SimpleLink> simpleList = **myAdapter.getSimpleLinksList**();
}
```

...
...

In the adapter class I have:

```
public MyAdapter {
    public List<SimpleLink> getSimpleLinksList() {
        List<SimpleLink> simLinks = null;
        String environment = AppFactory.getPropertiesObj();
```

...
...

```
class AppFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext acontext) {
        context = acontext;
    }
    public getPropertiesObj() {
        return getAppContext().getBean("propertiesBean");
    }
```

I get `NullPointerException` and see that `ApplicationContext` is `Null` here.

However at the `SpringJUnitTestRunner` class `MySimpleTester` I could find the applicationContext to be initialized correctly. I am not including the `mySimpleConfig.xml` and included files. The method in `MyAdapter` class `getSimpleLinksList()` works perfectly fine from the web application when run in the application server, and the appcontext is obtained there.

Only from the Spring tester is it not able to reach the static application context `AppFactory` class, as it is called statically through `AppFactory.getPropertiesObj()`. I had the classpath set correctly as other test classes are executing.

Comment: How would `MyAdapter.getSimpleLinksList()` even compile since `AppFactory.getPropertiesObj()` is **not** static?

Comment: In the actual program I do have the method static. It is while writing here I missed typing. public static String getPropertiesObj() {
        return getAppContext().getBean("propertiesBean").toString();
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the current ApplicationContext in MySimpleTester:-

```
public class MySimpleTester {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        myAdapter = (MyAdapter) applicationContext.getBean("myAdapter");
    }

@test 
public void testGetSimpleList() {
        List<SimpleLink> simpleList = **myAdapter.getSimpleLinksList**();
}
```

Comment: I did not get what you meant Amit. Please note that the MySimpleTester is the main Junit class so it needs Spring context Xmls loaded. So I do need it to have RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/spring/mySimpleConfig.xml"})         My requirement is in the AppFactory  class it should get the same ApplicationContext as the main Junit class. Why AppFactory is not able to get the ApplicationContext object reference and is null ???

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening as multiple application contexts are created. The AplliCationContext object is supposed to be singleton. But when from the static method we call the applicationContext again it is refering to altogether different confirguration. The ApplicationContext is not even initialised there.

This does not happen when the same module is called from Spring MVC webcontanier. It happens only when you try to use Spring tester classes RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class).  I can pass the AppContext in the business method but I do not want to change the bsiness method signature. I found some threads in spring community with similar issue.